# Testing if a point is inside a convex polytope formed by halfspaces in n-dimension

Tags: convex-polytopes, linear-programming, polytopes

Assume we have a convex polytope that is formed by the intersection of $k$-halfspaces in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

$$
a_{0,0}x^{n-1} + {a}_{0,1}x^{n-2} + ... a_{0,n-1} \leq 0 
$$
$$
a_{1,0}x^{n-1} + {a}_{1,1}x^{n-2} + ... a_{1,n-1} \leq 0 
$$
$$
a_{2,0}x^{n-1} + {a}_{2,1}x^{n-2} + ... a_{2,n-1} \geq 0 
$$
$$
....
$$
$$
a_{k-1,0}x^{n-1} + {a}_{k-1,1}x^{n-2} + ... a_{k-1,n-1} \leq 0 
$$

How do I quickly and efficiently test that some point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ lies inside this polytope ?

I would ideally like this computation to be done as efficiently as possible ?

(What I know so far ? If there were $k$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ forming the convex hull and we have to test if $x$ lies inside this hull, then we can frame this as a linear programming problem. I was wondering if the same treatment applies when they are halfspaces also ?)

Comment: You have already written your problem as a linear program.  The Simplex Method does not care whether your polyhedron is bounded or not.

Comment: If you construct a Dobkin-Kirpatrick hierarchical data structure for the polytope of $m$ vertices, then point location can be accomplished in $O(\log m)$ time per query.

Comment: Why not simply plug the value of $x$ in those $k$ inequalities ?

Comment: @F_G : That will involve a matrix multiplication which will be time-consuming for hidim data. I was hoping for a smaller time inequality check. Sorry if I have misunderstood the problem.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke : That looks interesting. I will refernece it

Comment: See also http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/32804/8067 Inclusion of polytopes